# Is it possible to use lists in Data driven Robot Framework tests

Tags: testing, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  resource_file.robot

*** Keywords ***
Test Template Fields
  [Arguments]  ${required_field}  ${optional_field}  ${ignored_field}
  Setup test  ${required_field}  ${optional_field}  ${ignored_field}
  Given Some data I want to test something

*** Test Cases ***
| * Test Case * | * Test Name *   | *Required Field*  | *Optional Field*   | *Ignored Field*                                     |
| 1 Test      | Test Template Fields | A_Required_Field | An_Optional_field | **Ignored_field1  Ignored_field2** |
```

Is it possible to pass a list of items to a Robotframework Keyword in Data Driven tests? (**Ignored_field1  Ignored_field2** in table above)

Answer (score 2):

```
 [Arguments]  ${required_field}  ${optional_field}  @{ignored_field}
```

Pass the argument as a list!